# any reason for Dart doesn`t allowing the following stmts?

Tags: dart, syntax

?? any reason Dart doesn't allow :

1:    multiple initialization on for loops i.e.
for ( int k=0, N=0; k< 55; k +=8, N +=30) {...}

2:    type unsigned int

3:    formatted print statements i.e. the equivalent of C function printf()

Comment: Because Dart is not C or another language, every language has its own rules. This [site](https://dart.dev/guides) is a good site where you can start to learn firstly

Answer (score 1):

1. Who says you can't?
2. I don't know the definitive reason, but Dart needs to transpile to JavaScript efficiently. `int`s are already a bit weird with Dart for the web, where they are backed by IEEE-754 double-precision floating-point numbers.  Having unsigned integer types too would make it even worse and more confusing.
3. Dart provides string interpolation, which is *far* less error-prone than C's `printf`.